# Combinatoric problem: Contest winner problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have this problem to solve where:
There is a contest between $m$ competitors.
Each competitor draws a number between $1$ to $N$ separately, and the winner is the one who drew the highest number.

The problem I'm having is to find out the probability that the contest fails.
The contest fails when there isn't a single winner - two or more competitors drew the same number and that number was the highest from all the other numbers that were drawn.
Generally, to draw the same number is not a problem as long that there is a competitor who drew higher.

I calculated the probability that two or more competitors drew the same number using the complement probability:

$$
\begin{multline}
1 - P(\text{all m contestants drew different number})  = 1 - \frac{N!}{(N-m)!} \frac{1}{N^m} 
\end{multline}
$$

Am I right?  I'm missing the part where the number that was drawn was the highest.

Appreciate your help, thank you in advance.

Comment: No, because you don't care if any of the other numbers are picked multiple times (unless I misunderstand the contest)—only the highest number matters.  So if $N = 10$ and the numbers picked are $4, 4, 6, 7, 7, 8$, then the $8$ wins and nothing else matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In how many ways can the highest score be $k$ and only appear once? There are $m$ ways to select who got that score and $(k-1)^{m-1}$ ways to select the scores of the other persons.

We conclude there are $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (k-1)^{m-1}m$ possible scenarios in total.

Comment: +1, and also pointing out you can pull $m$ outside of the sum, and that the actual desired quantity was the probability.  (Of course we just divide by $N^m$.)

Comment: @BrianTung Oh yeah good point ! And then you can close it with faulhauber or bernoulli polynomials or w/e

Comment: Thanks a lot!  been trying a lot solving this